# Truezip change file in-place

Tags: java, truezip

I want to change several lines in several files in several archives.
I could do it by unpacking to a temp-location, changing, and repacking.

However, I got the impression that by using truezip, I should be able to do this kind of handling in-place.

Can any of you help?

Comment: http://truezip.java.net/kick-start/tutorial.html

Comment: gives a nice way how to insert, delete and read files, but not how to update an existing line in an existing file without exporting said file..

Comment: It also says how to update a file. Do you want something more in-place than reading the individual files and writing back the updated versions?

Comment: this way you still have a temporary file outside of the archive, that you need to overwrite the original with.   If this is the only possibility, so be it.

Comment: Typically you would use a TFileInputStream or TFileReader to read the archive entry to memory, update it and then write back the result with a TFileOutputStream or a TFileWriter.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the TPath API and use Files.newByteChannel to request a SeekableByteChannel.

Comment: a lot of options. Going to try some after the weekend, and keep you posted on my choice.

Comment: I'm curious about how you solved this.

Comment: IIRC, I'd have to look at the code to be certain, is to make a temporary file, do a find and replace in the most inefficient way possible(loop over lines) and store it again.